# Are outsiders stronger in their native planes?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, lore, planes

In the campaign I'm playing in, there is internal conflict in the upper planes, and one of the lead instigators is a solar. We've killed it multiple times, but it keeps coming back with reinforcements. The party plans to go to the upper planes to finish it once and for all... But the DM says that it'll be stronger in its native plane.

Is this typically true – are outsiders stronger in their native planes? Is this true for other outsiders?

I'm fine if it's homebrew, but I'm just curious.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se - please take the [tour] while you are here. What setting are you playing? :)

Comment: What level is your group?

Comment: Related: [Why are Solars so powerful compared to other Outsiders in D&D?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67884)

Answer (score 11):

### Not by rules as written

There is nothing in the *Monster Manual* that would indicate so, if you refer to the [solar's stat block](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/solar). They do not even have lair actions.

Maybe what your GM means is that in his home plane he will have access to a much larger pool of **resources**, commanding large numbers of lower-ranked angels and celestial creatures, and will have access to his fortresses defense measures and maybe directly can call for or invoke his patron deity to come to his aid.

Or your GM's going to homebrew some lair actions and other power boosts. Wouldn't seem out of range. It's commonly accepted that the [high-CR opponents are too weak](https://dmdavid.com/tag/monsters-of-the-multiverse-should-have-given-foes-a-boost-but-it-didnt-next-chance-2024/) to challenge a high-level party anyways in 5e.

Comment: Also worth noting that a Solar is CR21, so if they have beaten it twice it was likely a depowered version that they fought

Comment: @SeriousBri Yeah, solars are no joke. I've run and played in several solar encounters. It's *stupidly* easy to TPK four or five 15th level characters. In my experience, solars punch above their weight class.

Comment: @SeriousBri He did not say anything about his groups level. Who knows, maybe they are all epic?

Comment: Since there are no epic rules or monsters it would be a different answer if that is the case, but possible, granted. That is why I asked under the question.